# Angular 2 - Circular dependencies causes 'unexpected value undefined' error

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, module, circular-dependency

I'm currently cleaning my app with a shared, features, and core module.

My **SharedModule** looks like :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TendanceNotePipe, 
    ColorNotePipe,
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,

    SearchBoxModule, // Need the FormsModule and the pipes TendanceNotePipe, ColorNotePipe

    TendanceNotePipe, 
    ColorNotePipe
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

The problem here is the SearchBoxModule need some things from the sharedModule, so I import it in the **SearchBoxModule** like this :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule, // Contains Pipes and FormsModule needed by the component of this module
    HttpModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    SearchBoxComponent,
    ResultsBoxComponent,
    ResultsListComponent
  ],
  exports: [SearchBoxComponent]
})
export class SearchBoxModule { }
```

I have error : `Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module SharedModule`. 
I think this is due to the circular dependency ?

The SearchBoxModule is a reusable module where the component is called multiple time in the app, sometimes twice in the same view, its place is in the ShareModule right ?

---

I tried to import manually the dependencies (Pipes and FormsModule) within the SearchBoxModule but I have a another error : `Type TendanceNotePipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules: SharedModule and SearchBoxModule`

---

The only way that I found is moving the declaration of pipes into SearchBoxModule from the SharedModule, then importing FormsModule and remove the SharedModule from its list of importation.

**But in this case the pipes aren't anymore in the SharedModule, where it should be !**

What I should suppose to do in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to create two separate modules. Or you can create one shared module and import all dependencies for SearchBoxComponent in the SharedModule and add to the declarations array and you export your search box component from your shared module. Drop the searchbox module.

Comment: Thx, I don't like create another top level Shared Module, but it seem's to be the cleaner way to do this... Basically, I created a TopSharedModule which contains all modules, directives, pipes and components which don't need any others dependencies, and I import it from within the SharedModule where I  keep the SearchBoxModule in place.